# How to change value the row of a listview returned from getApadpter().getView in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which has some rows off the screen. When I'm at the bottom of the list, position 0 of the list (ie the first item) is off the screen. I need to change the background color of the first row, but to get a reference to the view I have to use getAdapter.getView(), and when I set the background color it does not change.

I've tried smooth scrolling to the position first and then calling the method that changes the background color but still no luck:

```
if(position == 0) {
    mailList.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    selectRow(0);
}
```

This is where I change the background color:

```
public void selectRow(int position){

    // Get the row
    View row = getViewByPosition(position, mailList);
    // Highlight background colour
    row.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.Pallette_Peach_CC));
    // For every other row apart from 'position'
    // Check if read/unread and set background colour
    View v;
    for(int i = 0; i < mailList.getCount(); i++){
        if(i != position){
            v = getViewByPosition(i, mailList);
            if(Consts.mailBox.get(i).isRead()){
                v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.Ivory_Transparent_55));
            }else{
                v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.Ivory_Transparent_77));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I select the row:

```
// returns a specific row
private View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

After it smooth scrolls to position 0, the background is not re-set like it should be, but when I move to row 1 the background does get set. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put condition in `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method in adapter for changing color for specific row.

```html
if(position==0){
//Do your customization here
}
```

Comment: So simple. This solved my problem, thanks very much!